# How to set query variable in signalR alpha

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm porting my app from old signalR to new alpha version. On js side I set some variables using

```
$.connection.hub.qs = {'MyVariable1' : 'val1', 'MyVariable2' : 'val2'}
```

Then on the signalR server I was able to read these variables with

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    protected (string myVar1, string myVar2) GetValues() =>
            (
            Context.QueryString["MyVariable1"] ?? string.Empty,
            Context.QueryString["MyVariable2"] ?? string.Empty,
            );
}
```

I found that the server code needs to change to:

```
var httpContext = Context.Connection.GetHttpContext();
httpContext.Request.Query["MyVariable"]
```

However I couldn't figure out how to change my js to send query string to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass parameters in the query string you use when creating your hub connection e.g.:

```
let hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnection(
    "https://myserver/hub?MyVariable1=var1&MyVariable2=var2
```